# How to test database connectivity in python?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am accessing a MySQL database from python via MySQLdb library. I am attempting to test the database connection as shown below.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(self.server, self.user, 
                     self.passwd, self.schema)
cursor = db.cursor()        
try:
    cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
    results = cursor.fetchone()
    ver = results[0]
    if (ver is None):
        return False
    else:
        return True               
except:
    print "ERROR IN CONNECTION"
    return False
```

Is this the right way one should test the connectivity when writing unit testcases? If there is a better way, please enlighten!

Comment: corrected the error in code. Need to know if this is a right way to test?

Comment: *Why* do you want to *test* connectivity? What do you do if the test fails?

Comment: I am writing unit testcases for db access methods. So want to weed out the case when database access fails.

Comment: ick, bare except catching. Isn't there a more specific exception that'll be thrown that you can catch?

Answer (score 9):

I could be wrong (or misinterpreting your question :) ), but I believe that a connection-related exception gets thrown on `MySQLdb.connect()`. With MySQLdb, the exception to catch is `MySQLdb.Error`. Therefore, I would suggest moving the `db` setup inside of the `try` block and catching the proper exception (`MySQLdb.Error`). Also, as @JohnMee mentions, `fetchone()` will return `None` if there are no results, so this should work:

```py
try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(self.server, self.user, self.passwd, self.schema)
    cursor = db.cursor()        
    cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
    results = cursor.fetchone()
    # Check if anything at all is returned
    if results:
        return True
    else:
        return False               
except MySQLdb.Error:
    print "ERROR IN CONNECTION"
    return False
```

If you don't care about the connection and are just looking to test the execution of the query, I guess you could leave the connection setup outside the `try` but include `MySQLdb.Error` in your exception, perhaps as follows:

```py
db = MySQLdb.connect(self.server, self.user, self.passwd, self.schema)
cursor = db.cursor() 

try:
    cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
    results = cursor.fetchone()
    # Check if anything at all is returned
    if results:
        return True
    else:
        return False               
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "ERROR %d IN CONNECTION: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
return False
```

This would at least give you a more detailed reason of why it failed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Looks good to me.

My personal preferences:

- actually throw an exception if no connection
- you only need to fetchone, the test for None is superfluous (unless you're keen to enforce a minimum version of the database)

Comment: I did not get why is it superfluous. Could you please elaborate or point out how would you have coded  this?

Comment: "results" will be none when there is no connection. You'll probably get some other exception trying to do "results[0]" when its None.  Try it!

Comment: i like the idea of manually throwing an exception. which one to throw tho? lol