# Python3 psycopg2 commitment issue using variable vs function for connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

Can someone please explain to me why the defined test().commit() does not work as varcon.commit()? Everything else seem to work fine. (using vagrant virtualbox of ubuntu-trusty-32)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import psycopg2

varcon = psycopg2.connect('dbname=tournament')

def test():
     try:
         psycopg2.connect("dbname=tournament")
     except:
         print("Connection to Tournament Database Failed")
     else:
         return psycopg2.connect('dbname=tournament')


def writer():
    #db = psycopg2.connect('dbname=tournament')
    c =varcon.cursor()
    c.execute('select * from players')
    data = c.fetchall()
    c.execute("insert into players (name) values ('Joe Smith')")
    varcon.commit()
    varcon.close
    print(data)

def writer2():
    #db = psycopg2.connect('dbname=tournament')
    c =test().cursor()
    c.execute('select * from players')
    data = c.fetchall()
    c.execute("insert into players (name) values ('Joe Smith')")
    test().commit()
    test().close
    print(data)    

writer2()   #this seem not commited, but database registers the insert by observing the serial promotion
#writer()  # this works as expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this is because the `return` statement in a function block (`def`) is not equal to an assignment like `=` 
The psycopg2 connection function returns a connection object and this is assigned to `conn` or `varcon`

`conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres password=secret")`

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html

the `test()` function also returns the psycopg2 connection object but in *writer2* it is not assigned to a variable (memory place) meaning that there is no reference

this also explains why the database connection is established (initialized in the test function) but the commit does not work (broken reference)

(http://www.icu-project.org/docs/papers/cpp_report/the_anatomy_of_the_assignment_operator.html)

maybe try

`ami=test()`

`ami.commit()`

to establish a reference

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful response!  Can you please edit your second link to correct address (http://www.icu-project.org) as the project.org is something else.  Your suggestion worked.  Also, I found another way but not sure if it's a good practice: 
```test(): 
     try:
     psycopg2.connect('dbname=tournament')
     except:
         print('Connection to Tournament Database failed')
     else:
         conn2 = psycopg2.connect('dbname=tournament')
         conn2.autocommit = True
         return conn2```

Comment: in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735371/how-to-test-database-connectivity-in-python is the standard way how to establish and test database connection in python . you can do this like you want...

Comment: please do not upvote because i try to get unsung hero badge :)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `psycopg2.connect()` you open *new* connection to database.

So effectively your code executes SQL in one connection, commits another, and then closes third connection. Even in your `test()` function you are opening two different connections.

I use the following pattern to access PostgreSQL:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(DSN)

with conn:
    with conn.cursor() as curs:
        ...
        curs.execute(SQL1)

with conn:
    with conn.cursor() as curs:
        ...
        curs.execute(SQL2)

conn.close()
```

`with` statement ensures transaction is opened and properly committed around your SQL. It also automatically rolls transaction back in case your code inside `with` raises an exception.

Reference: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#with-statement

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is good to know.  I am still new to python and PostgreSQL.  I am using Udacity's program to study, and interestingly, they did not mention nor use this method.  I wonder why...  I also did not understand why simply stating var = psycopg2.connect(DSN) generates SQL connection automatically?  It is not like calling a function.  I would assume it becomes activated by execute method.  
I was not sure if it is good idea to establish global value of "conn", and then use it in various defined sql queries functions.

Comment: `connect()` is a function. PostgreSQL runs in separate process (or even server), before executing SQL you need to establish connection to it. Then you can reuse same connection multiple times. If done this way you should be prepared to re-establish lost connections (they might drop after some time). Real world programs obtain connections from connection pool http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/pool.html which takes care of managing connection lifecycle.