# Cannot connect MySQL database to apache-superset running in docker in production in the same server

Tags: mysql, docker, apache-superset

So I have been trying to connect MySQL database(to visualize the data in it) to apache-superset running in a docker container in production. The OS is Centos
I have checked on related questions and I don't seem to get a working answer.

It gives an error

> ERROR: Connection failed, please check your connection settings.

When i check the container logs this is the error i get

> WARNING:superset.views.core:Connection failed
> (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'HOST IP' (115)")
> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a host connection issue. Try the following order to identify the issue.

1. Check is host connection access from the outside world. [Here code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11896088/6345474)

2. Are you using the correct connection format for a superset?

```
mysql://username:password@HOST:port/database_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs : https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/mysql
maybe the last paragraph is the solution :
One problem with mysqlclient is that it will fail to connect to newer MySQL databases using caching_sha2_password for authentication, since the plugin is not included in the client. In this case, you should use [mysql-connector-python](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/) instead: